# Вывод номера по выбору города

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

```
<label>
    <span>Ваш город:</span>
    <select name="city">
        <option value="Саратов">Саратов</option>
        <option value="Энгельс">Энгельс</option>
        <option value="Балашов">Балашов</option>
        <option value="Балаково">Балаково</option>
    </select>
</label>
<span class="phone-wrap">
    <span class="for_ar">+7 (8452) 23-28-30</span> 
    <span class="callback-wrap">
        <img src="img/phone-icon.png" alt="phone">
        <a href="#callback">Заказать звонок</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

Как можно реализовать, чтобы при выборе определенного города, выводился определенный номер ? Я понимаю что через JS, может кто с кодом помочь. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Какой номер? Причем тут номер? Откуда берется номер?

Comment: Ну выбирают например "Балашов", в span выводится номер +9 000 000 00 00, выбирают "Саратов" выводится - +7 (8452) 23-28-30 и т.д.

Comment: `Откуда берется номер?`

Comment: Локальный сервер, нет данных. Номер думал, что можно прописать в JS, что вот если выбрали такой-то город, подставится такое то значение в спан

Comment: номер можно записать в `data` атрибут каждого `option` и брать оттуда к примеру.

Comment: Хорошо, можете показать это кодом?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим телефон хранится в `data` атрибуте каждого `option`, тогда при смене города, берем этот `option`, берем данные из атрибута `data` и вставляем в `span`:

```js
var cityPhone = $('.phone-wrap span').first();

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  cityPhone.text(optionSelected.data('phone'));  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <span>Ваш город:</span>
    <select name="city">
        <option value="Саратов" data-phone="666">Саратов</option>
        <option value="Энгельс" data-phone="999">Энгельс</option>
        <option value="Балашов" data-phone="777">Балашов</option>
        <option value="Балаково" data-phone="888">Балаково</option>
    </select>
</label>
<span class="phone-wrap">
    <span class="for_ar">+7 (8452) 23-28-30</span> 
    <span class="callback-wrap">
        <img src="img/phone-icon.png" alt="phone">
        <a href="#callback">Заказать звонок</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: @YourDeveloper, так же если телефон один и уникален, можете использовать его как option value.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin нельзя, если вдруг эти данные (название города) отправляются на сервер и нужно знать какой город был отправлен.....но тут правда много "но"  и "если"

Answer (score 2):

Смотря в каком формате хранятся данные о городах и телефонах.
Я такое делал через ajax, у меня данные лежали в mySQL, скрипт возвращал результат запроса данных о телефоне из таблицы городов.
У меня было как-то так:

```
$("#city").change(function(){
     var newcity = $(this).val(); //берем значение нового города
      $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'city.php',
     datatype: 'text',
     data: {city: newcity}, //передаем значение в скрипт
     success: function(datacity){
     //вставляем новое значение. К примеру:
     $(this).val(datacity);
     };
   )}
});
```

Как-то так :)

Comment: Там номеров всего 4, возможно как-то в JS прописать, без запроса в базы данных ?

Comment: Покажи уж тогда данные, в каком виде они хранятся

Comment: Нет данных, на локальном сервере всё делаю. Этот вывод обязателен через базы данных, в самом коде никто не выводит ?

Comment: Нет, необязательно. Почитай про хранение данных.
Это может быть и JSON, и XML, и обычный текстовый файл.